# Referencing a flutter file after importing it

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have imported a dart file into my main.dart. Now that I have imported it successfully, I would like to use the code of that file and I am not sure of how I will call the whole dart file I have imported into the main.dart file so that I can use some of the classes in the other file. It is telling me I have unused imports but I do not know how to use the files I have imported. Please help.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but when you import a file in dart you import all the classes within (expect the ones that start with _ (those are private))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `import`, use `part`.

In the file you want to import the other file in you want to use:

```dart
part 'imported_file.dart';
```

and in your imported file you want to add:

```
part of 'source_file.dart';
```